# How to echo resulted data as hyperlink instead of plain data?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/search.css">

</head>

<?php
include("productconfig.php");
$sql = "";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM weeklytbakl";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchbox']);

    $sql .= " WHERE description LIKE '%$search_term%'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<h1 align="center"> Search Product </h1>

<div class="box">
   <div class="container-4">

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="search_data.php">
Search for product: <input type="text" name="searchbox" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="icon">
</form></div> </div>

<p align="left"><a href="index.php"><img src="pic/home.png" onclick="AjaxResponse()" width="20" height="20"  /></a></p>
<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">



<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Code</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Image Link</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Instock</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Week 1</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Week 2</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Week 3</strong></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"><strong>Week 4</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['image']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['instock']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week3']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['week4']; ?></td>
        </tr>



        <?php }?>
        </table>
```

I'm obtaining data from my Mysql Database.
At the bottom part of the code inside  the data echoed is actually a website link of the image.
How can I make it appear as a hyperlink instead of plain text?
Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: <td><a href=''<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">Image(or text you want.)</a></td>

Comment: this is **HTML 101** stuff.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, cannot agree more! Dead simple HTML, a case of RTM I imagine...

Comment: @SamSwift *groan*, stuff I learned back like.....20+ years ago. It's old technology and if they believe it or not, still works to this day ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, not quite that long for me, you learnt it nearly as long ago as I am old ;P Only been doing this a few years and know this is basic! But with that said, *everyone needs a place to learn from others and ask question :D*

Comment: @SamSwift it's probably more than 20+ years; age plays tricks on one's mind. Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink says *"The term "hyperlink" was coined in 1965 (or possibly 1964) by Ted Nelson at the start of Project Xanadu."* W3 http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html says *"This chapter is a short history of HTML. Its aim is to..... 1989: Tim Berners-Lee invents the Web...."* ;-) Bit of history for the OP.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am sad enough to say - *I have spent the time to read that entire wikipage on nights to myself...*

Comment: @SamSwift [Seems like *the plot thickens*...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755719/how-to-echo-resulted-data-as-hyperlink-instead-of-plain-data#comment55279251_33755771), *lovely*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I saw that and amended my answer to accommodate it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

`<td><a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">Hyperlink</a></td>`

Here I have given the link as the source of the hyperlink so that it directs to the link provided.

Comment: "How can I make it appear as a **hyperlink** instead of plain text?"

Comment: Thanks @JamieSterling. Edited

Comment: @AshishChoudhary thank you for that. This is very useful for me. Do you know how I can adjust the size of the img src? Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can choose it as an answer if it helped. Image size can be adjusted using `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: @William1234 and AshlishChoudhary, I have added links and an example to my answer to help with this, I have links to w3schools, let me know if it is of use :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this has already been suggested by **Jamie Stirling**.

It is to do:

```
<td>
    <a href="<?=$row['image_or_uri'];?>">
        <img src="<?=$row['image']?>" height="120" width="120" /> 
        <!-- I made a whoopsie, you don't need to specify the 'px' in the tag as it does it for you :P -->
    </a>
</td>
```

Could be worth having a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp), good place to start from :)

Comment: http://www.w4schools.com/html/html_images.asp ? I think you meant "3" ;-) bad URL.

Comment: *ah,*... there we go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I cannot type 'ait! Haha

Comment: didn't you just do that? ;-)

Comment: @William1234, happy to help, if it solved your problem please consider marking as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <td><a><?php echo $row['id']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['code']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['image']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['description']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['instock']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['week1']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['week2']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['week3']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a><?php echo $row['week4']; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: You are missing a crucial element, **the hyperlink text** ;P

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">Link</a></td>
```

Comment: anchor tag cannot have ` />`